# Shortcut for "Create Folder" in GTK File Save Dialog

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gtk

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Create Folder" in a GTK file save dialog? I am referring to the action triggered by this button:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a bug issue filed for that. Even though it says with version 3.22.x (version now is 3.24) there should be a patch, the issue is still not resolved:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/957

Comment: Not sure who the negative people are who downvoted this. This perfectly answers the question.